# How to Create Document Library using Rest API in Alfresco

Tags: java, rest, alfresco

The documentLibrary is created on the first access But using HTTP `GET` request from Java program, the documentLibrary is not created.

Even though I faked a `GET` request `/share/page/site/ + shortName + /documentlibrary` But document folder is still not created. I can see the resulting HTML in the response. What could be the issue? Are there any javascript that runs once we first access ?

Answer (score 1):

Your URL point to the Share documentLibrary Page. But the data is loaded via AJAX from the repo via the following URL:
GET /share/proxy/alfresco/slingshot/doclib2/doclist/{type}/site/{shortName}/documentLibrary

AFAIK type can be: all, documents or folders

This URL may have changed in 4.2...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cmis family query:

```
nodeRef = b544cd67-e839-4c60-a616-9605fa2affb7;
xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
     '<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
xmlns:cmisra="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/restatom/200908/"
xmlns:cmis="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ns/cmis/core/200908/">' +
       '<title>name</title>' +
       '<summary>name</summary>' +
       '<cmisra:object>' +
       '<cmis:properties>' +
       '<cmis:propertyId propertyDefinitionId="cmis:objectTypeId">' +
       '<cmis:value>type</cmis:value>' +
       '</cmis:propertyId>' +
       '</cmis:properties>' +
       '</cmisra:object>' +
       '</entry>';
url: "/../alfresco/service/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/" + nodeRef + "/children",
method: "POST",
headers: {
"Content-Type": "application/atom+xml;type=entry"
},
xml:xml
```

name - document name;

type - document type;

nodeRef - folder id in Alfresco.

To create a document in type specify cmis: document.

I also advise you to read this article, which describes the other queries: http://jazzteam.org/en/technical-articles/list-of-alfresco-services/